# Сабантуй или сабантуй?

Tags: прописная-строчная

В предложении «В Казани прошел очередной Сабантуй (сабантуй)» как писать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Орфографический словарь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXlc0.png) разделяет написание на *Сабантуй* в прямом значении и *сабантуй* в переносном.
Поскольку в вашем случае имеется в виду прямое значение, то пишется с заглавной: **Сабантуй**.